# Why doesn't this work? OOP novice

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP, so please do not be harsh.

My task is that this:

```
 $color = new Color(127,0,0);
 $rect = new Rectangle($color, 100, 50);
 $rect->render();
```

Should bring to the page the following code:

```
 "div style="background-color:RGB(127,0,0);width:100px;height:50px"></div>"
```

Below is my OOP code. The goal was to use an abstract class `Component` and with an abstract method `render()`. I am trying to figure out why code doesn't work:

```
 class Color {
    protected $red;
    protected $green;
    protected $blue;
    public function __construct($red, $green, $blue) {
    $this->red = $red;
    $this->green = $green;
    $this->blue = $blue;
    }
 }
  abstract class Component {

    protected $color;
    protected $width;
    protected $height;

    public function __construct($color) {

    $this->color = new Color();

    }

    abstract function render();

  }
  class Rectangle extends Component {
    public function __construct($color, $width, $height){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->color = $color;
    $this->width = $width;
    $this->height = $height;
    }
    public function render() {
    echo "<div style='background-color:RGB(" . $this->color . ");width:" . $this->width .     "px;height:" . $this->height . "px'></div>";
    }
   }
  $color = new Color(127,0,0);
  $rect = new Rectangle($color, 100, 50);
  echo $rect->render();
```

Comment: What is failing? Do you have error messages turned on? Is the page failing to load entirely?

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Component::__construct(), called in /public_html/index.php on line 26 and defined in /public_html/index.php on line 18

Comment: You have to tell us (and understand, yourself! ) *what* is not working before you can get to *why*. Usually the first leads you directly to the second.

Comment: Its Working!!! Thanks xdazz for the function and Starx a reminder simple syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't passed the `$color` object to the parent class, and the spelling of `width` is incorrect

```
public function __construct($color, $width, $height){
    parent::__construct($color); //The parent also needs a $color as it is defined
    $this->color = $color;
    $this->width = $width;
    $this->height = $height;
}
```

Comment: @Sorrybyenglish, Yeah check the spelling of width, throughout the function. See the update

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo `$this->color`, you should define [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method for `Color` class.

```
 class Color {
    protected $red;
    protected $green;
    protected $blue;
    public function __construct($red, $green, $blue) {
        $this->red = $red;
        $this->green = $green;
        $this->blue = $blue;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "$this->red, $this->green, $this->blue";
    }
 }
```

And note there is a typo in your code, `with` should be `width`.

Also, the code in `Rectangle::__construct` method below

```
parent::__construct();
$this->color = $color;
```

should be

```
parent::__construct($color);
```

And the `Component` class should be (note the change of __construct):

```
  abstract class Component {

    protected $color;
    protected $width;
    protected $height;

    public function __construct($color) {

        $this->color = $color;

    }

    abstract function render();

  }
```

Comment: Oh thanks. This is what I want. I was understood but thank you ))

Comment: @Sorrybyenglish Yes, it's working for the variable name of `with`, I mean in the html output. Check your echo content.

Comment: My mistake sorry. I forgot sorry. I am 18 and i'm studying php during 6 months.

Comment: should be parent::__construct($color); with $this->color = $color;. it was work. But only parent::__construct($color); it doesnt work ))

Comment: Wow! Exactly... But how Component interact with Color class?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot... ))) HAHAH ))